# ServiceStack's IRedisClientManager + Ninject - use InSingletonScope?

Tags: redis, ninject, servicestack

I have an ASP.NET MVC application in which I've just started using ServiceStack's Redis client. I use Ninject as my IoC container. Currently my bindings look like this:

```
Bind<IRedisClientsManager>()
    .ToMethod(c => new BasicRedisClientManager("localhost:6379"))
    .InSingletonScope();

Bind<ICacheClient>().ToMethod(c => c.Kernel.Get<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient());
Bind<IRedisClient>().ToMethod(c => c.Kernel.Get<IRedisClientsManager>().GetClient());
```

I'm effectively creating one singleton instance of BasicRedisClientManager at app start-up to be used to instantiate in any request for an ICacheClient or IRedisClient. Is what I've done here correct for typical use cases? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes both the **BasicRedisClientManager** and the **PooledRedisClientManager** are both threadsafe and designed to be used as a singleton. The difference between the 2 is that BasicRedisClientManager returns creates a new Connection everytime whilst the PooledRedisClientManager maintains a pool of open Redis Connections.

Comment: Thanks! I'm now re-thinking my other binding above though. Specifically, IRedisClient is being injected into controllers where it hangs around until the gc comes through. Is that akin to keeping a critical resource open? Is it important to keep them short-lived (ie wrap their creation in a using statement?)